Удалить лог файлы в каталоге /var/log/apache2/domains/ при помощи crontab
Имеются: Ubuntu 22, Hestia CP, открытый внешний домен.
В каталоге /var/log/apache2/domains/ скапливаются лог файлы, размеры которых за 2-3 дня достигают 20 Гб.
Мне необходимо удалять каждый день (час, минуту, не важно) все файлы в каталоге /var/log/apache2/domains/ и для этого у меня есть только Crontab.
Я прописывал следующие команды
find /var/log/apache2/domains/LOG_NAME.log f -delete
sudo rm /var/log/apache2/domains/LOG_NAME
rm /var/log/apache2/domains/LOG_NAME
rm var/log/apache2/domains/*
Но ни одна из команд не удаляет файлы в указанной мне директории.

ошибки, которые вы при этом получали, угадать довольно сложно. гораздо проще вам самому о них рассказать.

Данную задачу можно автоматизировать с помощью logrotate, запуск которой повесить на systemd-timer.

Ошибка следующего характера
rm: cannot remove '/var/log/apache2/domains/LOG_FILE': Permission denied

/etc/crontab
#В час ночи каждый день чистим папку var/log/apache2/domains
#флаг -O3 - где O -оптимизировать, 3 - уровень три, сначала выполняются дешевые (т. е. быстрые) тесты, а затем, при необходимости, более дорогие
#флаг -ignore_readdir_race - игнорировать ошибки в случае если find не сможет получить через stat инфу о файле
#флаг -depth обработать вначале все под-каталоги прежде чем работать с самим каталогом
#флаг -mindepth 1 - минимальная глубина вложенности под-каталогов (чтобы не ушел за ..)
#<тут маска имени файла> - например www_mysite*, *.log
#<тут кол-во минут> - удалять только файлы измененные указанное кол-во минут назад (если опция не нужна то уберите -cmin +<тут кол-во минут>
m       h       dom     mon     dow     user    command
######################################################
0       1       *       *       *       root    /usr/bin/find -O3 "/var/log/apache2/domains/" -ignore_readdir_race -depth -mindepth 1 -name '<тут маска имени файла>' -type f -cmin +<тут кол-во минут> -delete


Таким образом, команда, добавляемая в интерфейс crontab получается вот такая?
/usr/bin/find -O3 "/var/log/apache2/domains/" -ignore_readdir_race -depth -mindepth 1 -name *log -type f  -delete

Для тестов вы можете запустить ее вручную и проверить правильно ли она отрабатывает
